# Proper way of specifying DataContext (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I just started working with WPF. In my new application I implemented notify icon with context menu first. Next I started building MVVM framework and found that the new changes impact the code already implemented.

I am using NotifyIcon from [Hardcodet](http://www.hardcodet.net/wpf-notifyicon). My initial version was something like this:

```
<Window x:Class="ScanManager.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:wpf="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit"
        xmlns:tb="http://www.hardcodet.net/taskbar" 
        xmlns:commands="clr-namespace:ScanManager.Commands"
        Title="Scan" Height="542" Width="821">
    <Grid Visibility="Visible" Loaded="form_Loaded">
        ...
        <tb:TaskbarIcon HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="357,537,0,0" Name="mainTaskbarIcon" VerticalAlignment="Top" IconSource="/Icons/TestIcon.ico" IsHitTestVisible="True" ToolTipText="Test Test" >
            <tb:TaskbarIcon.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Header="_Show" Command="{commands:ShowMainWindowCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                    <MenuItem Header="_Hide" Command="{commands:HideMainWindowCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                </ContextMenu>
            </tb:TaskbarIcon.ContextMenu>
        </tb:TaskbarIcon>
        <Button Name="hideButton"  Content="Hide window" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,408,50,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="92" IsEnabled="True" Click="hideButton_Click" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Next I started incorporating MVVM pattern based on article [The World's Simplest C# WPF MVVM Example](https://www.markwithall.com/programming/2013/03/01/worlds-simplest-csharp-wpf-mvvm-example.html). The example project adds DataContext pointing to a ViewModel class.

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <ViewModels:Presenter/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

This change affected the way the notification icon works. In a nutshell, the overriding methods `ICommand.CanExecute(object parameter)` and `ICommand.Execute(object parameter)` of the ShowMainWindowCommand and HideMainWindowCommand objects started receiving object `Presenter` defined in `Window.DataContext` instead of original `Hardcodet.Wpf.TaskbarNotification.TaskbarIcon`. And I am guessing this is because the added DataContext affects the `{Binding}` value of the `CommandParameter`.

The `Execute` method expects the parameter to be `TaskbarIcon` in order to identify the parent Window object, which then can be set shown or hidden.

The way I was trying to address it I moved all elements but the `TaskbarIcon` from Window to a UserControl, under a Grid and applied DataContext to the Grid

```
<UserControl x:Class="ScanManager.Views.SControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    ...
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance ViewModels:Presenter}">

    <Grid Visibility="Visible">

        <Grid.DataContext>
            <ViewModels:Presenter/>
        </Grid.DataContext>

        <Button Name="hideButton" Command="{Binding Path=HideMainWindowCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" Content="Hide window" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,408,50,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="92" IsEnabled="True" Click="hideButton_Click" />
        ...
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

It addressed the issue with notify icon, but I am wondering if this is right way of resolving the situation. I thought the other way could be to set `CommandParameter` in `MenuItem` in the original version after `DataContext` was added, to proper value, however I am having hard time figuring this out.

As the next step, I am trying to cast `DataContext` of the `UserControl` object to `INotifyPropertyChanged` in order to subscribe to `PropertyChanged` event, however the `DataContext` property comes in as `null`, presumable because it was set only to `Grid` and not to the `UserControl`:

```
    INotifyPropertyChanged viewModel = (INotifyPropertyChanged)this.DataContext;
```

Any guidance on putting these pieces together properly would be much appreciated.

**Edit**

Access Denied, these options are helpful for the Button element.
What if I would like to come back to the initial version at the top, the MenuItem element uses `Command="{commands:ShowMainWindowCommand}"` and `CommandParameter="{Binding}`". If I add `Window.DataContext`, is there a change that can be done to the MenuItem's `Command/CommandParameter` attributes in order to reference what they referred before (I assume, the parent element)? I tried `CommandParameter="{Binding Path=mainTaskbarIcon}"` and it did not work meaning, like before, the Execute/CanExecute receive null.

```
<Window x:Class="ScanManager.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:wpf="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit"
        xmlns:tb="http://www.hardcodet.net/taskbar" 
        xmlns:commands="clr-namespace:ScanManager.Commands"
        Title="Scan" Height="542" Width="821">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <ViewModels:Presenter/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid Visibility="Visible" Loaded="form_Loaded">
        ...
        <tb:TaskbarIcon HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="357,537,0,0" Name="mainTaskbarIcon" VerticalAlignment="Top" IconSource="/Icons/TestIcon.ico" IsHitTestVisible="True" ToolTipText="Test Test" >
            <tb:TaskbarIcon.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Header="_Show" Command="{commands:ShowMainWindowCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=mainTaskbarIcon}" />
                    <MenuItem Header="_Hide" Command="{commands:HideMainWindowCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=mainTaskbarIcon}" />
                </ContextMenu>
            </tb:TaskbarIcon.ContextMenu>
        </tb:TaskbarIcon>
        ...
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Please carefully read [Data Binding Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-binding-overview) first. Unless you set an explicit source object (by Source, RelativeSource or ElementName), a Binding's source is the object in the current DataContext of the target element of the Binding. Unless explicity set, the value of an element's DataContext is passed from its parent element by dependency property value inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

When you set datacontext it spreads to the inner controls as well and yes it affects Binding context. There is no need to create UserControl since it does not prevent context from spreading. In order to prevent it change datacontext of the control or specify binding source. For example, if you want to change context of the button.

Approach with DataContext override:

```
<Grid Visibility="Visible">

<Grid.Resources>
   <ViewModels:Presenter x:Key="buttonContext"/>
</Grid.Resources>

<Button DataContext="{StaticResource buttonContext}" Name="hideButton" Command="{Binding Path=HideMainWindowCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" Content="Hide window" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,408,50,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="92" IsEnabled="True" Click="hideButton_Click"/>
```

Approach with specifying source:

```
<Grid.Resources>
   <ViewModels:Presenter x:Key="buttonContext"/>
</Grid.Resources>

<Button Name="hideButton" Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource buttonContext}, Path=HideMainWindowCommand}" Content="Hide window" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,408,50,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="92" IsEnabled="True" Click="hideButton_Click"/>
```

Or you can also have ButtonContext property in your root viewModel and resolve it this way:

```
<Button DataContext="{Binding ButtonContext}" Name="hideButton" Command="{Binding Path=HideMainWindowCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" Content="Hide window" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,408,50,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="92" IsEnabled="True" Click="hideButton_Click"/>
```

How to subscribe to DataContextChanged event:

```
 public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContextChanged += MainWindow_DataContextChanged;
```

Handle event:

```
private void MainWindow_DataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.OldValue != null && e.OldValue is INotifyPropertyChanged)
    {
        ((INotifyPropertyChanged)e.OldValue).PropertyChanged -= MainWindow_PropertyChanged;
    }
    if (e.NewValue != null && e.NewValue is INotifyPropertyChanged)
    {
        ((INotifyPropertyChanged)e.NewValue).PropertyChanged += MainWindow_PropertyChanged;
    }
}

private void MainWindow_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
 ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to adhere to `Commanding`. Change your menu items to use a click event instead, and they can call command operation from the View's codebehind.

1. Add `Click="{Your click event name}"`
2. F12 on the click event to create/go to the event.

---

As an aside here is a way to bind a VM to a data contect without doing it in the XAML.

[Xaml: ViewModel Main Page Instantiation and Loading Strategy for Easier Binding](http://omegacoder.com/?p=1017)